# Correction of data from position hall effect sensor

Tags: matlab, sensors, effect, ripple

I have a problem with my hall effect sensors: I need to compute the rotational speed of a DC brushless motor with a hall effect position sensor. This sensor gives you COS and SIN which can be used to get the position of the motor. From that, I get my speed. However, because of mechanical problems, the SIN and COS are not perfect, and when I plot SIN = F(COS), this is what I'm getting:

[image: image1]

Resulting in ripples on my speed like this :

[image: image2]

Have you got any ideas on how I can get rid of this (I can't change the sensor neither the motor obviously)? I'm using Matlab 2017a.

Comment: Maybe average the data temporally?

Comment: Maybe the rpm of the motor is not constant? What are the x and y ticks in your second figure?

Comment: As per Cris's suggestion: the sample at 0, 0 seems spot on. You can just do revs/time to get an average

Comment: Also, you could just normalize any x- y- reading to 1. Or do theta = atan2(sin, cos)

Comment: Do you have timestamps for the readings? Cause it would be interesting to see how the signals deviate form perfect in time. I'd probably do a fit for the some wave in each direction, and create a distortion map of the Hall effect sensor based on the data. A simple parabolic least squares looks adequate here. Using the corrected data, you should get a nice circle.

Comment: What makes you think the sensor is wrong ? Did you have the actual motor RPM measured with a calibrated equipment before ?

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers you are awesome ! I can just average it, since I need it in real time application and average would slow too much my system. The rotational speed of the motor is constant, no doubt about this. Also I'm already using Atan2 to get position using angles.

Comment: @Hoki The sensor may not be wrong indeed, nontheless I can't change anything on a hardware level, so I need to deal with it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Is it possible to create such a map in real time with minimum computation time ?

Comment: @Denisbrobro. You need a lookup table computed offline from data like what you show. During operation, you just use the table.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I tried it, with 2 different tables, but the results are not satisfaying enough : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/41/2/1570520200-table1.png and https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/41/2/1570520200-table2.png The tables are made in such way that I associate directly a Sin/Cos couple with an agular position of the motor.